# achartengine remove chart background

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to remove the entire color background of my graph including this border black color, to start customizing with my own. I've tried:

```
    mrenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mrenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Is there anyway to get it all out there of there?

Comment: Hi, How you removed black color around graph? I need to make it transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the color to `Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255)` instead of `Color.TRANSPARENT`.

Comment: no dice. i still see that black border. i even tried parsing a hex value.

Comment: For the border, use renderer.setMarginsColor()